# Как грамотнее составить запрос с учетом нескольких значений из других таблиц по ключу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица `Table1`

ID / Info

Таблица `Table2`

ID / ID_from_Table1 / Info

Теперь мне нужно выбрать информацию вида

t1.ID,t1.Info,t2.Info (через запятую)

Наверное, надо было так и составить запрос изначально, но я не люблю такой возврат, поэтому в коде программы я создал модель такого вида

```
public class Table2
{
    string Info { get; set; }    
}

public class Table1
{
    string Info { get; set; }
    List<Table2> T2Items { get; set; }
}
```

и заполняю я ее двумя запросами. Сначала получаю результат запроса для таблицы 1, затем ищу множества для каждого элемента таблицы 1 в таблице 2

А в VM я уже вывожу List T2Items в виде строки элементов через запятую.

Но теперь мне потребовалось сделать поиск по полям. Чтобы искать по полю Table1.Info, достаточно просто изменить текст запроса с учетом строки поиска (вместо 'SELECT FROM' задать 'SELECT FROM WHERE'), но как искать в этом случае по множеству из таблицы 2 я не представляю. Точнее, есть мысли, конечно, но это будет много кода со сложной логикой.

Comment: Ну вот все таки гораздо лучше изначально было составить запрос из обоих таблиц и спокойно искать, все средствами sql. СУБД в любом случае гораздо быстрее сделает даже просто склейку двух таблиц

Comment: @Mike, склейку таблиц - возможно, но склейку значений - вряд ли. Имею ввиду перечисление Table2.Info через запятую. К тому же мне может понадобиться потом в другой форме именно список, а не перечисление через запятую. Тогда сервер базы будет выполнять Join, а клиент будет делать Split. двойная работа

Comment: А зачем серверу выполнять join он как обычно вертикально вернет а вы сразу к себе в массив загрузите. А если все таки надо что бы склеил, на mssql это конечно немного сложнее, чем на mysql, готовой функции нет. но в принципе и проблем особых нет

Comment: @Mike Как он вернет вертикально то? Я ведь написал в каком виде мне нужен вывод. Вертикально он вернет количество записей, равное количеству записей в t2, а в моем случае это лишний трафик и неудобство, потому что возврат организован постранично

Comment: так вы под `t1.ID,t1.Info,t2.Info (через запятую)` имели ввиду, что вам нужны отдельные колонки t1.ID, t1.info И _несколько_ t2.info через запятую. Я эту фразу понял так, что надо просто эти три значения через запятую вернуть и все. А трафик при вашей модели практически тот же идет.

Comment: @Mike, в моей модели каждый выполняет свою работу

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что "через запятую" в mssql очень сложно `select A.id,A.info,(select info+',' from Table2 B where B.ID_from_Table1=A.id FOR XML PATH (''))
  from Table1 A`  при желании можно добавить условия поиска в подзапрос в списке выборки или если нужны только записи содержащие определенный info из tab2 дописать в запрос `where exists(select 1 from tab2)`